# How does resistivity affect shielding (both DC electric field, and AC E.M. radiation)?

Tags: field-theory

I wondered if essentially we have an RC time constant, R relating to resistivity and geometry, C to geometry alone. So it takes a time for charge to establish itself in the right places so as to give a zero net field.

Thus, something like a carbon paper sheet would eventually shield a DC field perfectly, but would perform too slowly to keep up with AC (???)

Note:
(I'm more from an electronics background than physics, but I think this is the more approriate place to ask than the electronics forum...)